I am getting an error from Edge Browser's console. How can I solve this
enter image description here
Image of Error
when I open edge browser console then I am getting the error.
error says :

[Deprecation] -ms-high-constrast is in the process of being deprecated. Please see  for tips on updating to the new Forced Colors Mode standard.

[Deprecation] -ms-high-constrast is in the process of being deprecated. Please see https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/17/styling-for-windows-high-contrast-with-new-standards-for-forced-colors/ for tips on updating to the new Forced Colors Mode standard.


I want to solve this error.

This is a warning, not an error.  The warning seems pretty clear... That CSS rule is being deprecated.  The warning is suggesting that you don't use it, and provides a link to more information.  What specifically are you asking about this?

Yes, it's a warning. But I want to solve this warning why my console is showing error and how can I solve it? I didn't written any type of code in css file because I'm using tailwind css so I just added Tailwind directives to css file.

You can solve it by no longer using that CSS rule in the code.  Have you tried that?  Have you bothered to follow the link that has been provided to learn more about it?

I didn't written any type of code in css file because I'm using tailwind css so I just added Tailwind directives to css file.

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/17/styling-for-windows-high-contrast-with-new-standards-for-forced-colors/

I don't understand what that page is saying

If you're not using that code then you may be using a 3rd party tool which is.  You can try updating to the latest version of that tool, or perhaps contacting the vendor, or perhaps not using that tool.  You'll first want to debug and confirm specifically what code is producing the warning and where that code is used in your project.

A way is provided here to check how the application would look like if the old high contrast css is not supported anymore:   "To check your styles, you can disable the legacy implementation locally in Microsoft Edge:
Open a new window or tab.
Go to edge://flags/#edge-deprecate-ms-high-contrast in that tab.
Enable the Deprecate ‘-ms-high-contrast’ and ‘-ms-high-contrast-adjust’ flag, and then restart Microsoft Edge."
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2024/04/29/deprecating-ms-high-contrast/

Try to find code similar to this one:
 @media (-ms-high-contrast: none), screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .navbar{
    max-height: 47px;
  }
}

and remove it.

I have the same problem but the code is from Angular Material mdc components. I can override CSS from libraries but I cannot remove it.
